# Create a link that opens the user preferences of the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Can't get info anywhere on this - Am I right in saying its impossible.

I'm testing for cookies and would like to put a link within the notice paragraph directing the user straight to the cookie settings of that particular browser?

I'm using Javascript/jquery and RoR...

Any ideas or links you may know of would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. If it was, it would be a security issue.

By default, `chrome://chrome/settings/` will not be accessible. It throws the exception `Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://chrome/settings/`. Same applies to `about:` URLs in firefox.

You could probably hack certain browsers into doing that, but there is no standard cross-browser way of doing that.

Try it for yourself: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXAy6/)**

---

It is **possible** to access `chrome://` URLs through a chrome-extension for sure, when given the `tabs` permission.

Comment: Thanks - Was more about getting some direction. This was helpful.